# How to install a download .tar.bz linux kernel?

Tags: kernel, tar

I have downloaded the latest stable linux kernel release from this site

[kernel.org](http://kernel.org/)

My question is, how do I install it in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: If you have to ask how to install that in Ubuntu, then I strongly recommend you not to proceed. Although you can build+install a kernel by copying & pasting commands, it should not be done unless you want to learn something.

Comment: @Lekensteyn, can you move this comment as an answer so that I can accept it? Thank you.

Comment: I'd just delete this question if possible, my comment is not really an answer to the question and I am sure that several other questions/answers on this site already cover it.

Comment: Can't delete since it has an answer. I'll just accept the other one then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com) has a good [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) on the subject of building and installing a kernel.